# Google app engine php 'require'' not working as expected

Tags: php, google-app-engine

So I developed on my local machine using the Google App Engine Launcher where everything worked, then I uploaded it and suddenly it stopped working. Here is the code I'm talking about:

includes/require_login.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["username"]) or !isset($_SESSION["userId"])) {
    require "/templates/login.htm"; //This works locally
    exit();
}
?>
```

submitlink.php:

```
<?php
    require "includes/require_login.php";
    require "templates/submitlink.htm"
?>
```

And the require in the require_login.php is not working, but outputs this error:

```
Warning: require(/templates/login.htm): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /base/data/home/apps/e~seminarfach-abi-links/1.388897696415952665/includes/require_login.php on line 4 Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/templates/login.htm' (include_path='.;/base/data/home/apps/e~seminarfach-abi-links/1.388897696415952665/;/base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk') in /base/data/home/apps/e~seminarfach-abi-links/1.388897696415952665/includes/require_login.php on line 4
```

I also tried the following options, witch all result in this error(I think):

```
require "../templates/login.htm"; //This dosen't work on my local maschine.
require "/../templates/login.htm"; //This works locally
```

Just to make it clear: The require_login.php file is in a folder called includes. It tries to open a file called login.htm that is in a templates folder that foldes is NOT inside the includes folder but on the same level as the includes folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do the following:

```
require __DIR__."/../templates/login.htm";
```

You don't want to have a leading / because that points to the root directory of the file system.  If you don't include `__DIR__` then php searches relative to whatever file is first accessed by the initial request.

Comment: Works! Thank you! Any ideas why my version dosen't work?

Comment: If it works locally that would mean you have your code hosted in the root directory.

Comment: Nope it is not on C: directly (Windows user here) But a few subfolders deep on there.

Comment: To make it more clear the project is in `C:\Users\kjh\Documents\SF WEBSITE\appengine-try-php-master`

Comment: @ajon , is there anything to do with the permission of the folder?

Comment: @KetanModi I'm not sure what the message would be if the issue is permissions.  I would think it would be different, but it might not be.  php files must have read permissions by the user that is running the server.  I have also read that directories must have execute permissions, though I can't confirm that.

Comment: @ajon , please check this question , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48899618/require-is-not-working-in-php