# `require` is not working in php

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

This is the error which i am fetching right now.

```
PHP Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/base/data/home/apps/s~civic-planet-191520/20180221t115719.407805658953142647/web-service/web/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;/base/data/home/apps/s~civic-planet-191520/20180221t115719.407805658953142647/;/base/php_experiment_runtime/sdk')
```

My `autoload.php` file is placed in `vendor` directory , and i am loading `autoload.php` file from `web/index.php` file . `Web` and `vendor` directory both are at same lavel. Check below screenshot.

I am using this php code for load `autoload.php` file.

```
require __DIR__."/../vendor/autoload.php";
```

I have also try:

```
require(__DIR__. '/../vendor/autoload.php');
```

My project is load on google app engine.

[image]

Comment: Try `require dirname(__DIR__) . "/vendor/autoload.php";`

Comment: @mulquin, okay let me try

Comment: Did you check the file permisions? Is "/vendor/autoload.php" readable?

Comment: `PHP Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/base/data/home/apps/s~civic-planet-191520/20180221t121938.407806020838103175/web-service/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;/base/data/home/apps/s~civic-planet-191520/20180221t121938.407806020838103175/;/base/php_experiment_runtime/sdk') in /base/data/home/apps/s~civic-planet-191520/20180221t121938.407806020838103175/web-service/web/index.php on line 11` @mulquin

Comment: @Datz, also need to give permission in google app engine? Yes , then how should i check it and how should i change it?

Comment: @KetanModi https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/googlestorage/

Comment: @Datz, which kind of permission i have to change for this ?? can you explain it bit more?

Comment: @KetanModi sorry, I missed the "Google app engine" part.
Maybe this helps: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/googlestorage/advanced#using_php_include_and_require

Comment: i have the same problem

Comment: @jazz, are you use composer in your application? If yes , then please try to install composer first

Comment: @KetanModi yes i use composer, but im unsure if my autoload.php is configured properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the Composer executable globally for the dependency management
the same as it is done in [this Google PHP quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/quickstart#before-you-begin).